# add array to to old array in state in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am having a state in redux "politicianList". I don't want to replace the old state with new state. Instead I want to merge the old state with new state. Here is how I am doing it. I works but I want to know whether this is a correct react way of doing it?

```
export default function ImageReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case FETCH_POLITICIAN_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return {...state, politicianList : state.politicianList.concat(action.payload)};
            break;
```

Comment: As said in the answer you are doing it right. Maybe one change could be like this: `return {...state, politicianList : [ ...state.politicianList, action.payload] };` Or `...action.payload` if payload is also an array. By the way, you don't need to use break since you are using "return" in your reducer.

Answer (score 0):

Immutability is required by redux, and you're doing it exactly right, so to answer your question; it is the correct way of doing (out of many other correct ways)

`{...state}` creates a new object with the same properties as `state` without mutating `state`. You then overwrite the property `politicianList` in this new object.

The value you give `politicianList` is the previous value of `politicianList` concatenated with the payload. `Array.protoype.concat` is immutable and returns a new array.

All in all, you've created a new object with updated values without mutating the old object.

I can recommend [immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) to make it easier to work with immutable data.